# Redeclare - repeat function if array has more than one value

Tags: php, arrays, function, count, repeat

```
function test($str) {
  $c = count($str);
  if ($c>1) {
    foreach ($str as $key => $value) $result .= test($value);
  } else {
    $result = "<li>$str</li>\n";
  }
  echo $result ? "<ol>$result</ol>" : null;
}
```

The $str value could be either, something like this;

```
$str1 = "apple";
```

or something like that;

```
$str2 = array("apple","orange","pear");
```

If count($str) is more than one, which is $str is is_array, it repeats the $result.
But it doesn't work as I want..
I get an error *"Cannot redeclare test() (previously declared in..."*

The ideal output would be - $str1;

```
<ol>
  <li>apple</li>
</ol>
```

The ideal output would be - $str2;

```
<ol>
  <li>apple</li>
  <li>orange</li>
  <li>pear</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Please post the full error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check, if `$str` [is an array](http://php.net/is_array), e.g.:

```
function test($str, $first=true) {
  if (!is_array($str)) {
    $result = "<li>$str</li>\n";
  } else {
    foreach ($str as $key => $value) $result .= test($value, false);
  }
  return ($first ? "<ol>$result</ol>" : $result);
}
```

Also see [this example](http://ideone.com/hsFl0).

=== UPDATE ===

If you want to let it print directly, replace with:

```
function test($str, $first=true) {
  if (!is_array($str)) $result = "<li>$str</li>";
  else foreach ($str as $key => $value) $result .= test($value, false);
  if ($first) echo "<ol>$result</ol>";
  else return $result;
}
```

Also see [this example](http://ideone.com/uvVv6).

Comment: Thank you for your help!
It shows HTML with var_dump => var_dump(test("apple"));
but strangely, without it, it shows nothing => test("apple");

Comment: `echo test("apple");` will do it (also see [my updated exmaple](http://ideone.com/hsFl0)).

Comment: This is beautiful! Thank you @scessor ! Saved in my fav.. So sweet :)

Answer (score 3):

```
function test($str) {

  // Ensure, $str is a good argument of implode()
  if ( ! is_array( $str )) {
    $str = array( $str );
  }

  $result = '<li>' . implode( '</li><li>', $str ) . '</li>';

  return '<ol>' . $result . '</ol>';

}
```

*Remark:* Your method could return this:

```
<ol>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>
  <ol>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ol>
  </li>
  <li>3</li>
</ol>
```

Does this is really what you want to achieve? Does it really need to create nested `OL` structures?

Answer (score 1):

```
function testInternal($str){
    if(is_array($str))
        return implode('',array_map('testInternal', $str));
    else
        return '<li>'.$str.'</li>';
}
function test($str){
    echo '<ol>'.testInternal($str).'</ol>';
}
```